# What is the convention when populating a tableview from JSON in swift?

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, parsing, convention

I have seen someone create an object to receive the JSON data, then have an array of that object. and upon receiving new data from the JSON the Object array updates and the table view reloads.

How would i do this? I didn't really understand it, but i now need it as i need to receive data from PHP then parse it in Xcode onto a table view.

If you could, i would really be grateful if you could also show any optimisation tips.

I think they used the didSet variable in their code.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Give my a second, I will write you an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you meant with didSet right?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

    private var dataArray: [String] = [String]() {
        didSet {
            myTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let jsonRequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "yourEndPoint")!)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(jsonRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if let jsonArray: [[String: String]] = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves, error: nil) as? [[String: String]] {
                for jsonObject in jsonArray {
                    if let stringFromKey: String = jsonObject["yourKey"] as String? {
                        self.dataArray.append(stringFromKey)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = dataArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

}
```

You just need to exchange the JSON Parsing and Array type to fit your purpose

Comment: Thank you Neo, you are a life-saver.

Have a nice day!